# DialogMessageReceived event is not being triggered for M365 Subscription Office Version macOS BigSur (Version 11.3.2) for Excel

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

We are using Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync to open dialog to get credentials and DialogMessageReceived event is not called after providing credentials for MAC.

It is working fine for Windows, Office for web in chrome, safari but DialogMessageReceived event is not called for Excel on MAC.

Microsoft is rejecting our office addin submission due to this issue.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 60, width: 30}
    , function (result) {                   
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {                        
            loginDialog = result.value;    
            if (loginDialog != null && loginDialog != undefined) {                               

              loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, 
                function (arg) {
                    
                   //code written here when dialog message received
                });  

                                                         
            }
        }                   
    });
```

What should I add or change that it should start working in excel desktop for MAC?